# DOMDocument is not defined? Saving Data to XML

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays, dom

So i need help i have this code to edit a XML file but it keeps pulling an error called "DOMDocument is not defined"..

First question: what does that error mean?

Second Question:  is there a way to fix it?

Here is the code;

```
function starter ()
{
  var user = new Array(); 
  user[0] = {'woodres' : document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML}; 
  user[1] = {'stoneres' : document.getElementById("stone").innerHTML}; 
  user[2] = {'steelres' : document.getElementById("steel").innerHTML}; 

  var doc = new DOMDocument(); 
  doc.formatOutput = true; 

  var r = doc.createElement("user"); 
  doc.appendChild(r); 

  for (var resourceKey in user) 
  {       
    var resource = user[resourceKey]; 
    var b = doc.createElement("resource");

    var reswood = doc.createElement("reswood"); 
    reswood.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(resource['reswood'])); 
    b.appendChild(reswood);

    var resstone = doc.createElement("resstone"); 
    resstone.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(resource['resstone'])); 
    b.appendChild(resstone);

    var ressteel = doc.createElement("ressteel"); 
    ressteel.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(resource['ressteel'])); 
    b.appendChild(ressteel);
  } 

  r.appendChild(b);

  var userlogin = _SESSION['username'];
  var where=simplexml_load_file('data/'  + "" +  userlogin  + "" +  '/'  + "" +  userlogin  + "" +  '.xml');
  alert( doc.saveXML());
  doc.save(where) 
}
```

Comment: `DOMDocument` is part of *PHP*, not *JavaScript*. So is `simplexml_load_file`. And `$_SESSION`...

Comment: i knew that i tried to convert them using some converter online, is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a little bit confused. Let me describe the situation:

You intend to instantiate `DomDocument`, but that does not exist, as it is a PHP class. So the solution would be to write an equivalent server-side code and use that instead. If you want to let your users edit XMLs on the client-side, then you have to implement the needed infrastructure.

So, in short: the error was that you attempted to use PHP classes in your Javascript code and the solution is to not attempt to use PHP classes in your Javascript code. Instead, write a code which is logically equivalent with your needs.

Comment: Alright thanks, what i was trying to do was save 3 sets of spans, into the xml file but i cannot do php to do that but i though i could using javascript

Comment: is there a way to do this "document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML" using php?

Comment: There is no way to do that, because that's also mixing up the client-side and the server side. However, you can read the innerHTML with Javascript and post the content to the server. Note, that client-side (Javascript) is running on the user's machine and server-side (PHP) is running on the server. If you want to reach anything on the client-side with the server, then the client-side has to send the given data to the server. If you desire to reach server-data with your client-side, then the server has to send that to the client.

Comment: Not necessarily, because you only have to divide the tasks between client-side and server-side. You will always have to ask yourself questions like Should this task run on the client or the server? How can I minimize the number of messages in the communication between the server and the client? Is this a composite problem which should be divided between the server and the client? If so, which part should be done by the client and which part should be done by the server? Some tasks might be hard, but who said programming is easy? If my answer helped you, then please consider accepting it.